# Find answers of the questions from paragraph

Tags: algorithm

**Problem Statement:**
Given a paragraph and a list of questions which can be easily answered by reading the paragraph. Find the answers of the questions.

How shall I approach to solve this question? I know this is broad question but I want to know higher level approach for solving this problem.

**Sample Input**

> Zebras are several species of African equids (horse family) united by their distinctive black and white stripes. Their stripes come in different patterns, unique to each individual. They are generally social animals that live in small harems to large herds. Unlike their closest relatives, horses and donkeys, zebras have never been truly domesticated. There are three species of zebras: the plains zebra, the Grévy's zebra and the mountain zebra. The plains zebra and the mountain zebra belong to the subgenus Hippotigris, but Grévy's zebra is the sole species of subgenus Dolichohippus. The latter resembles an ass, to which it is closely related, while the former two are more horse-like. All three belong to the genus Equus, along with other living equids. The unique stripes of zebras make them one of the animals most familiar to people. They occur in a variety of habitats, such as grasslands, savannas, woodlands, thorny scrublands, mountains, and coastal hills. However, various anthropogenic factors have had a severe impact on zebra populations, in particular hunting for skins and habitat destruction. Grévy's zebra and the mountain zebra are endangered. While plains zebras are much more plentiful, one subspecies, the quagga, became extinct in the late 19th century – though there is currently a plan, called the Quagga Project, that aims to breed zebras that are phenotypically similar to the quagga in a process called breeding back.
>   Which Zebras are endangered?
>   What is the aim of the Quagga Project?
>   Which animals are some of their closest relatives?
>   Which are the three species of zebras?
>   Which subgenus do the plains zebra and the mountain zebra belong to?
>   subgenus Hippotigris;the plains zebra, the Grévy's zebra and the mountain zebra;horses and donkeys;aims to breed zebras that are phenotypically similar to the quagga;Grévy's zebra and the mountain zebra

**Sample Output**

> Grévy's zebra and the mountain zebra
>   aims to breed zebras that are phenotypically similar to the quagga
>   horses and donkeys
>   the plains zebra, the Grévy's zebra and the mountain zebra
>   subgenus Hippotigris

Comment: Can You provide an example?

Comment: @RomanHocke added example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to build a NLP classifier.
In its most simplest form, I suppose you can:

1. Find the most relevant set of key words from the paragraph and then match with the questions text using algorithms such as [N-Gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram).
2. Train the classifier to tag the words and form a body of knowledge between questions and answers

   For example - Key words: from questions- Zebras and endangered, matching text from paragraph - Grévy's zebra and the mountain zebra are endangered.

You can look at [Chapter 6 from Natural Language Processing with Python - Learning to Classify Text](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html) for how to build the classifiier.